# Accessing first column of pandas value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use value_counts() function from Python's pandas package to find the frequency of items in a column. This works and outputs the following:

```
57     1811
62      630
71      613
53      217
59      185
68       88
52       70

Name: hospitalized, dtype: int64
```

In which the first column is the item and the right column is its frequency in the column.

From there, I wanted to access the first column of items and iterate through that in a for loop. I want to be able to access the item of each row and check if it is equal to another value. If this is true, I want to be able to access the second column and divide it by another number.

My big issue is accessing the first column from the .value_counts() output. Is it possible to access this column and if so, how? The columns aren't named anything specific (since it's just the value_counts() output) so I'm unsure how to access them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`value_counts` returns a Pandas Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list("abc"), size=10), columns = ["X"])
df["X"].value_counts()
Out[243]: 
c    4
b    3
a    3
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

For the array of individual values, you can use the index of the Series:

```
vl_list = df["X"].value_counts().index
Index(['c', 'b', 'a'], dtype='object')
```

It is of type "Index" but you can iterate over it:

```
for idx in vl_list:
    print(idx)

c
b
a
```

Or for the numpy array, you can use `df["X"].value_counts().index.values`

Comment: Is .index or what? How did you know you could call .index on value_counts()? I checked the pandas docs and don't see any available attributes for value_counts(), and yet here I see .index and .name both working (i.e. value_counts().name). Where do I find that information?

Comment: It returns a Series.  You can see the .index syntax here:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series

Answer (score 37):

Use Panda's [`items()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mycolumn': [1,2,2,2,3,3,4]})
for val, cnt in df.mycolumn.value_counts().items():
    print('value', val, 'was found', cnt, 'times')

value 2 was found 3 times
value 3 was found 2 times
value 4 was found 1 times
value 1 was found 1 times
```

Comment: Clean approach!

Comment: getting `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`. `.items()` will work though.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the first column by using `.keys()` or `index` as below:

`df.column_name.value_counts().keys()`

`df.column_name.value_counts().index`